# How to get from the Faroe Islands to the Shetland Islands

Tags: transportation, faroe-islands

How do I get from the Faroe Islands to the Shetland Islands or the other way round? Is there anything besides a flight via Scotland?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Google Flights and Opodo don't find any flights between FAE and LSI at all. Kayak and Swoodoo only find pretty silly connections with at least two stops, of which one is always over night. Going via Edinburgh (total time 6:35, one stop) seem to be the best option, but you won't find it in any of the common search engines. Perhaps it's not possible to buy both legs on one ticket, but it might still be a viable chance to take with a 3:45 hours connection in Edinburgh.

Comment: If you're not in a hurry I'm sure you could find a fisherman heading to the North Sea who'd drop you off for some monetary consideration.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo:  [Flightconnections.com](http://www.flightconnections.com/) doesn't return any results either, despite the fact that (I thought) it ignores whether tickets can actually be purchased for the itineraries.  I wonder what's going on with that.   Also note that a connection is in principle possible in Aberdeen as well.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert There are currently no flights from the Faroe Islands to Aberdeen. The only other common destination from Tórshavn and Lerwick is Bergen, Norway (BGO), but the there are no flights on a common weekday. FAE-BGO is flown Mo/We/Th/Fr, while LSI-BGO is only flown on Tu/Sa. flightconnections.com does not seem to know any flights at all to Lerwick.

Comment: Edinburgh is the only viable Option, and it can be booked through Atlantic Airways's website

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo:  Good to know.  Apparently [LoganAir announced last fall that they would be operating between FAE and Scotland this summer,](https://www.loganair.co.uk/scotlands-airline-launches-largest-ever-flight-schedule/) but as of this date the airport doesn't appear on their booking website.  The route must have been postponed or quietly dropped.

Comment: Can you give a general idea of your price range and time constraints?  Charter, air taxi, or other unscheduled flights might be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the quickest route is making your way to Edinburgh and flying with Atlantic Airways from there. As pointed out by @Dorothy, direct ferries haven't been around for nearly a decade.

This flight can be booked [**here**](https://www.atlantic.fo/en)

Answer (score 5):

Direct ferry is no longer an option, since Smyril discontinued its Shetland link on the Denmark-Iceland route which, until 2008, ran from Lerwick to Tórshavn.

You can reach the Faroe Islands:

[By sea](http://www.visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/transport/getting-here/by-sea/#sthash.vxP9vGGD.dpuf): Smyril Line’s M/S Norröna sails from Hirtshals in the north of Denmark and from Seyðisfjørður in Iceland.

[By air](http://www.visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/transport/getting-here/by-air/#sthash.rg5xoIXJ.dpuf): on either the Faroe Islands’ national airline, Atlantic Airways, and Scandinavian Airlines (SAS).